# How to add sub options in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce

I am using the latest 3.0.2.0 version of opencart.
For options I want to add sub options, also I want to have pricing for sub options as there is for options. There is a lot of talk about dependent options from 2009 and earlier for opencart, but it never came in core release. Why is everyone saying that it is too difficult to implement dependent options ?
What is the solution ?

**Option Colour**

> RED (+$2)

**Sub option Size**

- Small (+$3)
- Medium (+$4)
- Large (+$6)

**Option Colour**

> BLUE (+$2)

**Sub option Size**

- Small (+$5)
- Medium (+$7)
- Large (+$8)

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720224/how-to-set-custom-price-in-opencart-products

Answer (score 1):

yes, opencart should give the dependent option as default. if you want to use dependent option you can use [this extension](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=6787), this will let you create dependent option with price increment if you want.